# QuartzCore.framework problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, quartz-graphics

I am trying to use QuartzCore Framework but when adding this framework to my iPhone application, I am told that the files (e.g. CIColor.h and others) are missing but those missing files exist on my hard drive under /system/library/

In addition to the QuartzCore Frame work, I am using the following frameworks: cocos2d, cocoa.framework, openGLES.framework, openAL.framework, foundation.framework, UIKit.framework, and APPKit framework.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're including the wrong framework. iPhone frameworks are located in

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.x.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

Note that CoreImage classes (including CIColor) are NOT included in the QuartzCore framework for iPhone.